# FPDF error: Cannot open

Tags: fpdf

I am using the code on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983432/applying-watermarks-on-pdf-files-when-users-try-to-download-the-files/4995085#4995085)

and calling this `WaterMark::applyAndSpit($fileWithFullPath);`. The full error is

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for WaterMark::applyAndSpit(), called in C:\wamp\www\pdf\pdfgen.php on line 89 and defined in C:\wamp\www\pdf\pdfgen.php on line 20
>   FPDF error: Cannot open

line 20 is seen on the code on that original page linked above. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the linked-to code, the function applyAndSpit takes two arguments, and apparently you are only supplying one.