# Adding vertical text with fpdf/fpdi in php

Tags: php, pdf

I have a script that builds up a multi page pdf from a database blob. This pdf works and outputs fine current but I need to add a vertical line of text down the left hand side of each page. I have managed to get this to work for some of the pdfs but for some I get a corrupted file error. Does anyone have a different way of adding vertical text I can try using fpdf/fpdi.

This is what I have so far:

```
function buildBSIPDF($filename){
global $supplier;

$pdf = new FPDI();
$i = 1;
$pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($filename);

//create text to append
$sideline = "Some text here";

while($i <= $pagecount){

    //$pdf->setSourceFile($filename); 
    // import page 1 
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($i); 
    //use the imported page and place it at point 0,0; calculate width and height
    //automaticallay and ajust the page size to the size of the imported page 

    //$s = $pdf->getTemplatesize($tplidx); 
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx); 

    // now write some text above the imported page 
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', '12'); 
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
    //set position in pdf document
    $pdf->SetXY(20, 20);
    //first parameter defines the line height
    $pdf->RotatedText(5,250,$sideline,90);
    $i++;
}
$pdf->Output($filename, 'F');
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
class PDF extends FPDF { 

function Rotate($angle,$x=-1,$y=-1) { 

    if($x==-1) 
        $x=$this->x; 
    if($y==-1) 
        $y=$this->y; 
    if($this->angle!=0) 
        $this->_out('Q'); 
    $this->angle=$angle; 
    if($angle!=0) 

    { 
        $angle*=M_PI/180; 
        $c=cos($angle); 
        $s=sin($angle); 
        $cx=$x*$this->k; 
        $cy=($this->h-$y)*$this->k; 

        $this->_out(sprintf('q %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f %.2f %.2f cm 1 0 0 1 %.2f %.2f cm',$c,$s,-$s,$c,$cx,$cy,-$cx,-$cy));
     } 
  } 
} 

$pdf=new PDF(); 
$pdf->AddPage(); 
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10); 
$this->Rotate(10); 
$pdf->Write(20,'this text is crooked');
$this->Rotate(0);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I still get the same error for rotated text. It works fine for text at no angle, even using your function but with an angle of 0 is fine. As soon as I put any angle on though I open the pdf in acrobat and get the error: "An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not be able to read the page correctly"

Comment: Yeah other pdf readers are fine, I've narrowed down the problem which is outlined here relating to unbalanced Q and q operators in the pdf. My OOP knowledge however is limited so I don't know if I'm doing something wrong in relation to my loop in terms of implementing what these guys are saying - http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10318839-RESOLVED-FPDF-Rotating-Text

Comment: @MattWade As far as understand from the link you need to put **$this->Rotate(0);** or in your terms **$pdf->Rotate(0);**. This should set the balance 'q' and 'Q'. No idea whatever these are. Must be something related to pdf format specification.